# Разделить очень длинную строку на много маленьких по 100 символов

Tags: golang

Есть, длинная строка, ее нужно разделить на много строк по 100 символов, в php
ранее было так

```
$data = file_get_contents('1.txt');
$array = str_split($data, 100);
```

Сейчас переписываю алгоритм на **GOlang**  -- встроенной функции не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n := 5 // по сколько символов делить строку 
str := "dsfjskjreirqurieuoifakjdfkroiquerjakfsl" // наша строка
l := len(str) // длина строки
arr := []string{} // конечный масив разделенных строк
from := 0 // от куда будем разделять строку (с какого номера символа)
to := n // до куда (до какого номера символа) //
for { // бесконечный цикл
    if l > to { // если длина строки больше номера конечного символа
        arr = append(arr, str[from:to]) // делим добавляем
        from = to // назначаем начало с последнего добавленного
        to = to + n // новое конечное
        continue
    }
    arr = append(arr, str[from:l]) // добавляем последнее оставшиеся символы
    break
}
fmt.Println(arr)
```

[ПОСМОТРЕТЬ ПРИМЕР В ДЕЙСТВИИ](https://play.golang.org/p/WdR1pRzoW_R)
После перехода нажать на "Run"

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!

Comment: Если ответ решил ваш вопрос, примите его, нажав галочку рядом с ним